# window.onkeypress only working in the beginning when file is opened in browser

Tags: javascript, window, console.log

I have this code:

```
      function myFunction1() {
        alert('Hi');
      }

      function myFunction2(a, b) {
        console.log(a + b);
      }

      function myFunction3(a, b) {
        console.log(a - b);
      }

      // first event type
      window.onkeypress = myFunction1();

      // second event type
      window.addEventListener("keyup", myFunction2(3, 2));
```

The problem is that myFunction1 and myFunction2 only run when the website is first loaded. So, as soon as I open the website, without doing anything, "Hi" pops up and in the console, "5" is printed. But when I press a key or click anywhere, nothing happens. Is there a reason why this isn't working?

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that you invalid invoke for events

```
window.onkeypress = myFunction1();
window.addEventListener("keyup", myFunction2(3, 2));
```

change it to below

```
window.onkeypress = myFunction1;
window.addEventListener("keyup",() => { 
      myFunction2(3, 2)
});
```

Also,in order to make keyup event work,you need to use console.log instead of alert in myFunction1

```js
function myFunction1() {
  console.log('Hi'); // using console.log instead of alert,otherwise keyup will not work
}

function myFunction2(a, b) {
  console.log(a + b);
}

function myFunction3(a, b) {
  console.log(a - b);
}

// first event type
window.onkeypress = myFunction1;

// second event type
window.addEventListener("keyup", () => {
  myFunction2(3, 2)
});
```